# Access calculate date according to input

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

In Access 2016 I would like to calculate a future date from different inputs.

The table is set up with three columns:

- The "date of last review" (in `dd/mm/yyyy`)
- A "risk assessment" (which can take on the values of `low`, `medium` & `high`)
- A "future review date".

I would like to calculate the "future review date" (in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`) according to the "risk assessment".

So in 1 year for a low risk, in 2 years for medium and in 3 years for a high risk.

I appreciate your help and answers.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *DateAdd* for that, for example:

```
TwoYearDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 2, Date())
```

Edit, as expression:

```
=DateAdd("yyyy", Switch([Risk Assessment] = "low", 3, [Risk Assessment] = "medium", 2, [Risk Assessment] = "high", 1), [Date of Review])
```

Comment: This won't work since I need one input in column three that adds either 1, 2 or 3 years onto the date from column one, according to the text input ( low medium high) in column two.

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from your original wording. Still, use DateAdd which also respects leap years. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this by using the following formula in the Expression Calculator (Date):

`[Date of Review]+IIf([Risk Assessment]="low",1095,IIf([Risk Assessment]="medium",730,IIf([Risk Assessment]="high",365,0)))`